# Calling posix_spawn on iOS

Tags: ios, c, filesystems, posix, foundation

I am looking to calculate the size of a folder with millions of files (~1K each), and `NSFileManager` / `NSDirectoryEnumerator` just aren't cutting it.

It crossed my mind to do this at the Unix level instead of Foundation. I understand `fork()` is discouraged/disabled, and the preferred way is to call `posix_spawn` and redirect/pipe output to a C string buffer. How can this be done?

Discouraged implementation:

```
FILE *fp;
int status;
char output[PATH_MAX];
NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"du -sk %@", folderPath];
fp = popen([cmd UTF8String], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"could not get file pointer");
    return 0;
}
while (fgets(output, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"size and path: %s", output);
}
status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    NSLog(@"could not close file pointer");
} else {
    NSLog(@"closed file pointer");
}
```

Comment: Where did these files come from? What kind of iOS app is this?

Comment: They are proprietary files used by my app...for now let's please defer discussions about reducing the number of files on disk ...

Comment: The suggestion was actually to count as added or off device...

Comment: I have considered that option, and it is a possibility. Since the unix disk usage command is so fast, I want to explore that more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something faster than the CoreFoundation methods, use `opendir()`, `readdir()`, and `stat()` directly to enumerate the directory and get the sizes of files.

Ultimately, though, it's likely that you are running into speed limitations of the storage on your iOS device, so this operation may never be fast for the number of files you're dealing with.